# Problem 3.14(e) in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

If $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers, define its arithmetic mean $\sigma_n$ by 
$$\sigma_n \colon= \frac{s_0 + s_1 \cdots + s_n}{n+1} \, \, (n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots). $$ Put $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 1$. Assume $M < +\infty$, $\vert n a_n \vert \leq M$ for all $n$, and $\lim \sigma_n = \sigma$. Prove that $\lim s_n = \sigma$.

I haven't been able to fill in the proofs in the steps of the outline suggested by Rudin.

Can anyone please help me out with coming up with a solution to this problem?

Comment: See in http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/solution.html